# External JS File not Working with html within html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a pretty straight forward problem and i have tried everything to figure out. I am just practicing with JS events. When i put the following function in a script tag within html it works perfectly fine but when i shift it to external file it doesn't work. I have no script tags in the external file as i saw in one of the related answers. The external file is attached properly to my html because some of the functions within the same external file work perfectly but some do not one of which is this:
this is the complete js code. prac1.js

```
 function getElementBy()
    {
     elem = document.getElementById('my_id').value;
     alert(elem);
    };
    
    
    
    function changeColor() {
        document.getElementById("fname").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    };
    document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener('focus', changeColor);
    
    function makeFieldYellow() {
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    };
    function makeFieldWhite() {
        document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    };

    function checkAddress(fieldId) {
        if (document.getElementById(fieldId).value === "") {
            alert("Email address required.");
        }
        }
```

this is the body of my html. Just haphazard elements for practicing events

```
<body>
    
    <a href="index.html" onMouseover="this.style.color='green';">Home Page</a>
    <p>Failed Event check again</p>
    <p id="loris" onMouseover="expand();">Slow Loris: Mouse over for more info</p>
    <p>Running a function on click</p>
    <div><button id='btn'>Click Me</button></div>
    <p>Failed Event check again</p>
    <div><button class='btn1'>Click Me Again</button></div><br>
    <p>Getting value of an html attribute through funtion</p>
    <div><input id='my_id' value="Hello This is test">
        <button onclick="getElementBy();">getElementById</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p> Changing image on mouse over</p>
    <div><img src="images/p1.png" width="100VW" height="100VH" onmouseover="src= 'images/p2.jpg'" width="100VW"
            height="100VH">

        <p>on focus function</p>Enter your name:<br> <input id="fname" type="text">
        <p> on focus and on blur inside the html tag</p>
        Email:<br>
        <input type="text" size="30" onFocus="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow';"
            onBlur="this.style.backgroundColor='white';">
        <br>
        <p> on focus and on blur function in external</p>
        Name:<br>
        <input id ="color" type="text" size="30" onFocus="makeFieldYellow();" onBlur="makeFieldWhite();">
        <p>Clear the input field when it gets focus:</p>
        <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Blabla">
        <p>Alert when the email is not submitted</p>
        <form onSubmit="checkAddress('email');">
            Email:
            <input type="text" id="email">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        <script src="prac1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Very likely your code runs before the DOM is fully rendered.    Please show where exactly you place your `script` elements.

Comment: Most likely, the `#fname` element does not exist yet when this code is ran because you inserted the `<script>` tag before the element. Try moving your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: my script tag is the last line before closing body tag. I have many functions in external file adding events to the elements even after this html element.html element is        Enter your name: <input id="fname" type="text" > when i put it like this Enter your name: <input id="fname" type="text" onFocus="changeColor();" > it works but when i put the function inside html file then it works even when i do not add the onfocus attribute in input tag

Comment: We need more info, then. Otherwise, we'll just make blind guesses and waste time. Please  [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67675568/edit) to add a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the minimal HTML and JS we need to reproduce the issue. Only then we can be certain we're giving you a correct answer

Comment: Your buttons and what not are not attached to event listens, so they have no idea how to call the JavaScript functions you have in  your script. Do something like this to link the script to the html: `element.addEventListener("click", myFunction);`

Comment: @FuruiCoder I copy/pasted this in an HTML file and a JS file called `prac1.js` next to it, and the event listener for changing the input's background color works. Maybe you have other code in your "real" project which may interfere with this?